# Reverse-engineering tool for code generation of Hibernate annotated DTO/DAO classes

Tags: java, hibernate, code-generation, maven-plugin

I have the following questions concerning code generation for Hibernate annotated DTO/DAO-s:

- Is it possible to use a reverse-engineering tool such as hibernatetool to generate DTO/DAO-s along with annotations (as opposed to the xml configuration, I have seen working).
- If there is such a tool, is there a Maven plugin which can be used as well?
- If Hibernatetool only supports xml based configuration (and there is no other tool which can generate annotated classes), why doesn't hibernatetool support this, if the framework has already 
  been supporting annotations for such a long time?

I know there are tons of code generators out there (from sql4java to oAW and firestorm). But I am looking for a good code generator that can produce DTO/DAO-s from an existing database, instead of having to use UML for this. If this generator can produce Spring configurations as well, it would be great.

Thanks for your time,

Martin

Comment: You can try hibernate-tools-maven-plugin. https://jonamlabs.com/how-to-use-hibernate-tools-maven-plugin-to-generate-jpa-entities-from-an-existing-database/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by reverse eng in this context but Spring-Roo does every thing that you seem to be needing .Spring-Roo generates complete boiler plate code including DAO .

Comment: I mean that I have an existing database. There are tools that can read the metadata and produce the necessary classes for you based on the table relationships.

Comment: Yes see **Database reverse engineering** in this link http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/os-springroo2/?ca=drs-

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising! I will try it out and let you know what happens! :-)

Comment: I'll most-definitely do so! :)

Comment: Although I don't quite like what it produces, this seems to be somewhat of a solution. Thanks for pointing it out. I tried it. I'll play around with it and see if it can really do what I need.

Comment: Thanks Carl:) being new here first day happy with points , yes it is in infancy at the moment and it does give fairbit of meta code . What we do at work is to just remove annotations like @roo and someother scaffolding but yes you are right it does have unneeded stuff in it.

Answer (score 3):

You can try **Telosys Tools**, an Eclipse plugin for code generation 
working from an existing database with customizable Velocity templates

See: http://sites.google.com/site/telosystools/
Eclipse Marketplace : http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/telosys-tools

This tutorial includes JPA entities generation : https://sites.google.com/site/telosystutorial/springmvc-jpa-springdatajpa

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at [Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/spring-roo) a database reverse engineering tool for DB to Spring configurations. There exists an eclipse integration, so that you can do that from within eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse-based [JBoss Tools](http://www.jboss.org/tools) can generate JPA-annotated entities for you (but not DAOs, I think).

As usual for Hibernate projects, [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/3.1.0.GA/en/hibernatetools/html/plugins.html) is confusing and hardly understandable, but the functionality is there.

There are also a set of [Ant tools](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/3.1.0.GA/en/hibernatetools/html/ant.html) which have been ported to a [Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/maven-hibernate3/hibernate3-maven-plugin/). Here's the [ant version of what you probably need](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/3.1.0.GA/en/hibernatetools/html/ant.html#d0e5215) (the docs for the maven version are virtually non-existing)

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for more of a IDE-independent solution, as my project is Maven-based and I use Idea.

Comment: @calrlspring OK, updated my answer. You can either use ant via the antrun plugin or the hibernate3-maven-plugin (if you understand the documentation, which I don't). I'd go for the antrun plugin.

Comment: My impression of the hibernatetool and the hibernate3-maven-plugin is that they only produce non-annotated code, but *hbm.xml configured code. I've already gone through their docs. If somebody could confirm or deny this suspicion of mine, I'd quite appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: @carlspring no, I'm pretty sure they also support a [`<jdbcconfiguration>`](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/3.1.0.GA/en/hibernatetools/html/ant.html#d0e4875). Otherwise they'd be pretty useless.

Comment: I just checked the Maven plugin again. It only works with hbm files.

Comment: The jdbcconfiguration (I believe) is a different thing, as explained here:

`When using the <jdbcconfiguration>, the ant task will read the database metadata and thus will perform a reverse engineering of the database schema into a normal Hibernate Configuration. It is from this object e.g. <hbm2java>can generate other artifacts such as .java, .hbm.xml etc.`

Thus, as far as i understand, it will generate the classes along with the *.hbm.xml configs, which would obviously mean that it doesn't produce annotated classes, but only as XML mappings.